# Problem saving rails marshal in sqlite3 db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, marshalling

This is what I tried

```
f = 1.2
f = Marshal.dump(f) #\004\bf\v1.2\00033
```

after that I tried to save this f into text column and this is an error I got.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLException: unrecognized token: "fϾ1.2 33" (Ͼ is male symbol, but I can't find one).
```

Comment: don't forget to mark answers solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i use a simple wrapper in my model that dumps the data and encodes it base64 so that it is a raw string:

```
def data=(data)
  write_attribute :data, ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(Marshal.dump(data))
end

def data
  Marshal.load(ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(read_attribute :data))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

phoet's answer is good, I only added support for empty values so you don't get error while loading.

```
def education=(data)
  write_attribute :education, ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(Marshal.dump(data))
end

def education
  data = read_attribute :education
  if data
    Marshal.load(ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(data))
  else
    nil
  end
end
```